# Unable to create a resource on Azure

Tags: azure, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to create a Power BI Embedded resource on Azure in a suscription where I have an owner role and my deployement fail with this status message in Operation details :

[image]

[image]

Do you know where the problem comes from?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the command you have run?

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: I just tried to create it on Azure portal. I edited the post with the picture